# Factor variable into weekdays

Tags: r, datetime

I have a variable for the date of medical admission. However, it is not properly formatted. It is a factor and formatted as "DDMMYEAR HRMN", like "01012016 1215", which should mean "01-01-2016 12:15". How can I reformat it and assign weekdays?

Comment: if you could provide a small dataset with ```dput()``` that would make things easier to set up the code you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `as.POSIXct`/`strptime` to convert to date time and then use `weekdays`.

```
df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date, format = '%d%m%Y %H%M', tz = 'UTC')
df$weekday <- weekdays(df$date)
```

For example,

```
string <- '01012016 1215'
date <- as.POSIXct(string, format = '%d%m%Y %H%M', tz = 'UTC')
date
#[1] "2016-01-01 12:15:00 UTC"
weekdays(date)
#[1] "Friday"
```

Comment: should i do the same for each observation?

Comment: You don't have to do this for each observation. If your dataframe is called `df` and column `date` you can pass entire column in `as.POSIXct` and `weekdays`, see first part of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use lubridate to parse the date, then weekdays from base R to get the day of week as a character.

```
library(lubridate)

d <- dmy_hm("01012016 1215")

weekdays(d)
```